# How to post a gridview rows data when a checkbox checked state becomes true?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, gridview, checkbox

**SCENARIO**

- Imagine a gridview with three columns.
- Column **A** contains a row specific **value**.
- Column **B** contains a **checkbox**.
- Column **C** contains a **button**.

**CURRENTLY**

- Data is posted on button click using row command *(As below)*.
- Data is only posted if the rows checkbox is checked.

**EXAMPLE**

```
Protected Sub gv_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewCommandEventArgs)
  Dim rowIndex As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)
  Dim row As GridViewRow = gv.Rows(rowIndex)
  Dim CB As Boolean = DirectCast(row.FindControl("cb"), CheckBox).Checked

  If (e.CommandName = "Save") Then
    If CB = True Then
      /*Post Data*/
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

**QUESTION**

How to post a gridview rows data when a checkbox checked state becomes true?

**Requirements:** Column **B** needs to read column **A**'s value. Remove the need for column **C** all together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### How to use a checkbox bound to a gridview row to submit data

```
  Protected Sub cb_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim row As GridViewRow = DirectCast(DirectCast(sender, CheckBox).NamingContainer, GridViewRow)
    Dim rowIndex As Integer = row.RowIndex
    Dim cb As CheckBox = DirectCast(gv.Rows(rowIndex).FindControl("cb"), CheckBox)
  End Sub
```